# Java - File Shared File Locking Issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have file locking and unlocking methods as follows,

Lock method,

```
fileLock = fileChannel.tryLock();

if (fileLock != null)
System.out.println("File is locked");
```

unlock method,

```
fileLock.release();
```

Now, this two methods are accessed by two concurrent processes. Now, if one processes crashes, before unlocking, another process can't access the file until JVM is closed. Can anybody help me, is it possible (and how) to specify some time limit for locking the file.

Comment: Are the `release()` calls enclosed in a `finally` block, after a `try{...} catch(){...}` . Why one of the Thread would crash silently ? One more question. You say : different processes, that means different  java Threads or really different OS processes

Comment: @Arpssss: By "process" do you mean "thread"? If a process crashes, to me that means that JVM _is_ closed. I suspect your ``fileLock.release()`` may need to go in a ``finally`` block.

Comment: @Ash, No, I have finally. But, for simplicity, I have not wrote that. And I have process, not thread.Thanks.

Comment: Okay. So you have two Java applications running, and one of them crashes, exiting the JVM (and that process) but leaving the file locked? What OS and JVM are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use singleton pattern. Then only one thread will access to your file.

Comment: -1. Meaningless. Not an answer. OP is talking about multiple *processes.*

Comment: Sorry, apparently I did not understand correctly this problem.